# How to refresh php table by var obtained via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm coding a mini web project to learn about php/html/java. The page I'm coding contains a table that use php code in it. This php code allows me to connect to my db and get the values I want to show in the table. Then I have a select box that has return the value of the selected field (via javascript?). This value has to be used refresh the php table. So the value has to be sent to the php code (via Ajax?) and refresh the query I make to my db so the table will show new values. This is waht I have now:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Test</title>  
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #9C3;
}
p {color:black;}
.table_test {
    font-family: Constantia, Lucida Bright, DejaVu Serif, Georgia, serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div align='center'>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>test!</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="table_test">  
  <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' bgcolor='#F6F6F6' bordercolor='#FFFFFF'>  
    <tr>  
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'></td>
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Festa</td> 
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Preu</td>  
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Entrada</td>
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Final</td>
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Estil</td>
      <td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>Llista</td>  
    </tr>

<?php

    include ('connection.php');
    include ('functions.php');

    $dw = date("w");
    echo "Avui es el dia: $dw";

    $query = 'SELECT disco_id, party_name, price, hin, hout, style, list FROM disco_var WHERE day = '.$dw;
    $result = mysql_query($query,$connect);

    while ($reg = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $disco_id = $reg['disco_id'];
        $disco_name = get_disco_name_from_id($disco_id);
        $hin = substr($reg['hin'],0,5);
        $hout = substr($reg['hout'],0,5);
        $price = $reg['price'];
        if ($reg['list'] == 1) $list = "Apunta't!";
        else $list = "-";

        echo "<tr>  
             <td width='150'>".$disco_name."</td>  
             <td width='150'>".$reg['party_name']."</td>  
             <td width='150'>".$reg['price']." e</td>
             <td width='150'>".$hin."</td>
             <td width='150'>".$hout."</td>
             <td width='150'>".$reg['style']."</td> 
             <td width='150'>".$list."</td>
             </tr>";
    } 

    include ('close_connection.php'); 
?> 

  </table>

</div>
<p>Veure un altre dia de la setmana:
  <select name="day_select" id="day_select" onchange="dayChanged(this);">
    <option value="1">Dilluns</option>
    <option value="2">Dimarts</option>
    <option value="3">Dimeces</option>
    <option value="4">Dijous</option>
    <option value="5">Divendres</option>
    <option value="6">Dissabte</option>
    <option value="0">Diumenge</option>
  </select>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript"> //Here is the problem!!
    function dayChanged(opt)
    {
    //What should be the code here?
    }
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

So I want de var in php $dw to get refreshed by the value of the option selected in the select box (onClick function). Then the other problem is how to refresh the table with this $dw value.

I'm new with php/html/java coding and I'm really stucked with it. Thank you.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: *sidenote:* few HTML suggestions: use only lowercase tag names; don't mix single & double quotes; avoid inline CSS; table property is deprecated in HTML5 (well, you didn't use DOCTYPE); last, use DOCTYPE to specify HTML standards

Comment: JavaScript problem: you didn't set `width` and `height` in your JS function, and you didn't make use of parameter `opt`.

Comment: *sidenote:* last but not the least, `Java != JavaScript`.

Comment: Why MySQLi and not mysql_*?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor That was a mistake (width height). It was from an example code. I edited it.

Comment: MySQL libraries in PHP are deprecated for many years and will be removed on coming version. Switch to other libraries for better functionality & security

Comment: Hi, if you want to refresh the table on ajax then bring the table on ajax on page load. This code is showing the PHP renders the table first time but its not rendering the table via ajax which means next time if you want to new table values you need to do Post back which will effect other fields on the page too. On page load call the PHP ajax function to generate table, then on selected index change call that ajax function again with filter value. I hope you understand.

Comment: I understand that (more or less) but I have a mess with how to code it (same file? How I bring the table with Ajax in load page??)